# Type 'NSColor' has no member 'black'

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, nscolor

I'm working with Swift and SceneKit in Xcode 9.2. I've been applying color to geometry with `NSColor`, but all of a sudden (gradually) most of my colors get the type `NSColor` has no member `.colorname`. Like my game compiled and ran just fine, and then on the next compile, I got an error with `.cyan`. I changed it to `.black` and it ran. Then another color got an error, and then most of the colors got an error.

Here's an example:

```
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.black
```

the options that I have left are:

`.blue`, `.green`, `.int`, `.rawValue`, `.red`, `.yellow`.

What happened to all the colors?

EDIT: I cleaned up the project, it all compiles without warnings but I still only have 4 colors and they all render gray. I printed out the nodes diffuse colors to console and they read correct.

I've also imported Cocoa framework.

EDIT: I FOUND MY MISTAKE.

I accidentally replaced the name of an enum with `NSColor` while doing a find and replace. That's why `SKColor` worked, because it was a new name.

I am so embarrassed.

Comment: Try cleaning the project.

Comment: is this a mac or ios project?

Comment: it's a mac project. i just tried cleaning the project but something else went wrong. says it's missing info.plist input.

Comment: That's probably because you don't import Cocoa.  You should use SKColor with SceneKit.

Comment: importing SpriteKit and using SKColor works, but NSColor should work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor(srgbRed: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
```

In this way you create a color with your own RGBs values, so in this way you can get the color black. The last parameter, alpha, is the value of opacity and it needs to be 100 in order to see the color

Comment: I tried this and that option is not available either. when I write it out like that I get error "Extra argument 'green' in call". The only options that don't return an error are the ones I listed in the original question like NSColor(rawValue: String), which I've tried but it also renders gray

Answer (score 1):

In your case the better way is to use this syntax:

```
NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

In iOS you should use the syntax like this:

```
cube.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.45, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1.0)
```

In macOS the syntax is like this:

```
sphere.firstMaterial?.reflective.contents = NSColor(calibratedRed: 99.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Remember, the alpha (aka opacity), specified as a value from 0.0-1.0. Alpha values below 0 are interpreted as 0.0, and values above 1.0 are interpreted as 1.0.

And, of course, you can specify the colorspace explicitly (like `sRGB`):

```
init(srgbRed: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
```